# Need help identifying SMD, 6 pins, 1.6x1.6mm, top marking 82S

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Does anyone know what it might be?
Dimensions 1.6x1.6 mm, 6 pins, top marking 82S.

upd:
This is CarAudio Board Motrex MXTM200.

[image: 82S SMD]

[image: 82S SMD]

Comment: A context would help

Comment: Looks like a [5.4V low dropout voltage regulator](https://fk5jw4ohpftbbsd4fvgd7pmtzq-ac5fdsxevxq4s5y-m-hqew-com.translate.goog/tech/xinpin_1783824). Not an answer because I can't find a proper datasheet.

Comment: Alexey Murzin - Hi, FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list (which includes adding more context, as already commented), the better the chances of identification. Thanks.

Comment: here is voltage on pins - https://i.imgur.com/E5PG3CY.jpeg